# Currency symbol doesn't shown

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

there is a problem on my magento 1.9.2
the Currency symbol dosen't shown with the price , I did enabled from admin panel but still doesn't shown

I hope you can help me with it.

Comment: Please make sure your machine has support for the symbol.

Answer (score -1):

Currency symbols are handled by Zend_Currency and I havent experienced any issues with this before.

My guess is your problem may be elsewhere.

Are you using a special webfont that maybe doesnt have support for this currency symbol? If the symbol is not in the font, you wont be able to see it.

To make sure, check the HTML source of your page.